# sizers and controls next to notebooks

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, sizer, wxnotebook

I am facing layout problems implementing controls next to a notebook.

The Problem is, the notebook and the controls next to it are properly aligned as intended, but the ones on th window in the notebook are placed on top of each other, as if there was no sizer used.

I appreciate any kind of input how to fix this.

edit: provided example code to demonstrate the problem

Header test.h:

```
class mainwindow : public wxFrame{
  public:
    mainwindow(const wxString &title);
     wxWindow *notebookwindow[2];
     wxTextCtrl *onnotebook[2];
     wxNotebook *notebook;
     wxTextCtrl *onmain[2];

     wxBoxSizer *box[4];
};

class myapp : public wxApp {
  public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

test.cpp

```
// program test
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/notebook.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include "test.h"

mainwindow :: mainwindow (const wxString & title) 
  : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(1000, 800)){
      notebook = new wxNotebook(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200, 200));
      notebookwindow[0] = new wxWindow(notebook, wxID_ANY);
      notebookwindow[1] = new wxWindow(notebook, wxID_ANY);

      notebook->AddPage(notebookwindow[0], wxT("This"));
      notebook->AddPage(notebookwindow[1], wxT("That"));

      onmain[0] = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("on main 1"));
      onmain[1] = new wxTextCtrl(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("on main 2"));

      onnotebook[0] = new wxTextCtrl(notebookwindow[0], wxID_ANY, wxT("on notebook 1"));
      onnotebook[1] = new wxTextCtrl(notebookwindow[0], wxID_ANY, wxT("on notebook 2"));

      box[0] = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
      box[1] = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
      box[2] = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

      box[0]->Add(onmain[0]);
      box[0]->Add(onmain[1]);

      box[1]->Add(onnotebook[0]);
      box[1]->Add(onnotebook[1]);

      box[2]->Add(box[0]);
      box[2]->Add(notebook);

      notebookwindow[0]->SetSizer(box[1]);
      this->SetSizer(box[2]);

  }

bool myapp::OnInit(){
  mainwindow *mainfr = new mainwindow(  wxT("test"));
  mainfr->Show(true);

  return true;
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(myapp);
```

and the makefile

```
main=test.o 
flags=-std=c++11 -g 
folders=tables sources
gui=`wx-config --cxxflags --libs`


all: $(addprefix doto/,$(main)) 
    $(CXX) $(flags) $^ $(gui) -o test.exe 

doto/%.o:%.cpp %.h
    $(CXX) $(flags) $< $(gui) -c -o doto/$(notdir $(<:.cpp=.o))

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm doto/*.o *.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `wxNotebook` likes its pages to be fully assembled when they're added. So, moving

```
notebook->AddPage(notebookwindow[0], wxT("This"));
notebook->AddPage(notebookwindow[1], wxT("That"));
```

right before

```
this->SetSizer(box[2]);
```

fixes the problem.

---

Another fix is to force a layout on the notebook page itself after it's fully set up, that is, without changing anything else in the original code, add

```
notebookwindow[0]->Layout();
```

right before

```
this->SetSizer(box[2]);
```

---

I'm not sure if this behaviour should be considered a bug. I would expect a call to `Layout()` on the top-level parent to propagate everywhere and avoid such issues, but it looks like it doesn't work like that in this case.

I don't have time to investigate any further right now; it would be great if we could get VZ.'s opinion on this.

Comment: the first one does not appear to work, but the 2nd bit fixed the issue

Comment: @wka Strange, I wonder what's the difference that made it work on my side. What version of wx are you using, and on what OS?

Comment: 2.8 on ubuntu 14.04, gcc version 4.8.2

Comment: @wka I'm using wx 3.0.2 on windows, this might explain the difference.